# Can you add metadata to a folder in a document library?

Tags: web-part, document-library, metadata

I am making a visual webpart for SharePoint 2010 that displays files and folders from a document library, and I want to keep ordering to folders. I want to be able to sort folders so I need a way to store the order number of a folder. If I check on sharepoint in the browser, I don't see a way to add any info to it.

Is there a way to do this programatically in c#?

I want to avoid keeping the order number as a part of the folder name, something like:
"1. Folder A"

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with SharePoint Server 2010 or later you can consider using the Document Set feature.  A Document Set is essentially a folder that can be defined with a content type (includes meta-data) as well as other useful things like workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Folders in SharePoint are unnecessary pain in the ass. Folders will

- Not help your case in searching
- Will increase the Url length

As Mike said, use the documents set! Document sets inherit form folders and help manage group of documents as a single entity. It is nothing more than a content type that can be attached to any document library and make use of it's features.

See example: http://geekswithblogs.net/venkatx5/archive/2010/11/30/what-is-document-sets-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx